# combine \oldstylenums and \textsc

Tags: fonts, small-caps, oldstylenums

I would like to have a command that combines `\oldstylenums` for numbers in the argument and `\textsc` for text in the argument. I believe that a solution using some for loop is possible, but I think there must be a simpler solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

I get \oldstylenums{1s}

I want \oldstylenums{1}\textsc{s}

\end{document}
```

[image: M(n)WE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well of course what you *really* want in that case is a font with small caps and old style numerals. As a real or virtual font, then You would just access the font and TeX wouldn't have to do anything. But virtual fonts are not really so popular these days, do perhaps a TeX loop:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

I get \oldstylenums{1s}

I want \oldstylenums{1}\textsc{s}

\makeatletter
\def\zzz#1{%
\@tfor\tmp:=#1\do{%
\ifcat1\tmp\relax\oldstylenums\tmp\else\textsc\tmp\fi}}
\makeatother

\zzz{1s}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cfr-lm` package provides a complete set of virtual fonts for Latin Modern that supports oldstyle digits, among other things.

Comment: Ohh you should give that as an answer then as it's a better answer.

Comment: I prefer this one. I really only need it for short pieces of text.

Answer (score 8):

The `cfr-lm` provides support for oldstyle figures in Latin Modern, among other things:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[rm=oldstyle]{cfr-lm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

1234567890

\textsc{I want 1234567890}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but is it that this enables them _everywhere_?

Comment: @tohecz Of course; why wouldn't you want it everywhere? You either always use oldstyle figures (except in formulas or, in general, for numbers in their mathematical sense) or never.

Comment: well I'll give you a +1 even if @tohecz prefers my answer:-)

Comment: @egreg And also not in tables, I think. (Or is that wrong?)